# Counting files normally within a directory using Python

Tags: python, loops, sorting, lambda, counting

I am iterating through a directory of HTML files and trying to print the filenames in ascending order. The way humans would normally count them.

---

The desired output I'd like:

> **At file 9 in the directory:**
>
> The prev vid is 08--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&FKgTxV_W39Y.html
>
> The next vid is 10--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&HvsE0284W3g.html
>
> **At file 10 in the directory:**
>
> The prev vid is 09--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&8jhh21EFlqg.html
>
> The next vid is 11--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&gSAfguVusZU.html
>
> ...
>
> **At file 12 in the directory:**
>
> The prev vid is 11--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&gSAfguVusZU.html
>
> The next vid is 13--PL4OFZnQ3wLGlJ7_SioKhwvsckGY0ZENSh&JAx5IvBvHyA.html

And so on and so forth.

---

My code works fine for directories that have less than 100 HTML files, I get the desired output. But the counting gets ruined for directories with over 100 HTML files.

[image: The Wrong Output]

---

Here is my code. *Sorry* if it looks like spaghetti, it's not the prettiest code:

```
for index, file in enumerate(iterable_directory):

    # Ignore any 'index.html' file in the video directories
    if file.startswith("index"):
        continue

    # See if there are only 2 files present in directory
    if len(iterable_directory) == 2:
        prev_video = '#'
        next_video = '#'
        print(f'At file {index+1} in the directory:\n')
        print(f'The prev vid is {prev_video}\nThe next vid is {next_video}\n')

        continue
    else:                        
        # Grab the first and last html file in each playlist directory
        first_item = iterable_directory[0]
        last_item = iterable_directory[-2]

        # Check if the file is an html file and ignore it if it is an 'index.html' file.
        # Then, check if the file is the first or last file in the directory.
        if file.endswith(".html") and file != "index.html":
            if file == first_item:
                prev_video = '#'
                next_video = f"{iterable_directory[1]}"

                print(f'At file {index+1} in the directory:\n')
                print(f'The prev vid is {prev_video}\nThe next vid is {next_video}\n')

                continue
            elif file == last_item:
                prev_video = f"{iterable_directory[-3]}"
                next_video = '#'

                print(f'At file {index+1} in the directory:\n')
                print(f'The prev vid is {prev_video}\nThe next vid is {next_video}\n')

                continue
            elif (index + 1 < len(iterable_directory) and index - 1 >= 0):
                prev_video = str(iterable_directory[index-1])
                next_video = str(iterable_directory[index+1])

                print(f'At file {index+1} in the directory:\n')
                print(f'The prev vid is {prev_video}\nThe next vid is {next_video}\n')

                continue
```

---

This lambda function with the sorted function does sort the files in the order I want it, but I still can't seem to figure out how to put it into my code to make it work.

```py
sorted(iterable_directory, key=lambda x: int(x.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split('-')[0]) if x!="index.html" else 0)
```

I would greatly **appreciate** any help, I've been at it for a week and I've been losing sleep over it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you need:

```
import glob
import os

HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
BASEDIR = os.path.join(HOME, 'html') # The directory containing the html files

def getfilelist():
    filelist = []
    for htmlfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '*.html')):
        base = os.path.basename(htmlfile)
        if not base.startswith('index'):
            filelist.append(base)
    return sorted(filelist)


def main():
    filelist = getfilelist()
    for i, _ in enumerate(filelist[1:-1], 1):
        print(f'At file {i} in the directory\n')
        print(f'The prev vid is {filelist[i-1]}')
        print(f'The next vid is {filelist[i+1]}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```